# Does the background location manager must be in appDelegate? iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, background

Hi I'm trying to figure if the locationManager must be in the appDelegate to be called while in the background or if the appDelegate has to be locationManager delegate for background updating to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, any class in your app can be the location manager delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It need not necessarily be in AppDelegate, but should preferably be in a singleton that can be accessible from the AppDelegate to be accessed in the Background.

Comment: Sorry I misread yesterday but the locationManager delegate has to be the appDelegate to be able to be called while in the background. Is that what you said? I did it and it worked but if I could have the delegate somewhere else it would be a better architecture I think